# Rustacean way to parse a date from &str [Rust]

Tags: rust, refactoring

I have this function, but I feel that it's duplicate code. I was wondering if anyone here shares how to make it more `rustacean`. I'm still learning Rust, and I thought this could be a good example to share.

```rust
fn check_and_transform_dates(start_date: &str, end_date: &str) -> (i64, i64) {
    let message: String = format!(
        "Data could not be downloaded ❌, please make sure your dates
    are in the following format YYYY-MM-DD
    (ie. 2020-01-01), your dates are Start Date: {}, End Date: {}",
        &start_date, &end_date,
    );
    let start_date_parsed: i64 = Utc
        .ymd(
            FromStr::from_str(start_date.split('-').collect::<Vec<&str>>()[0]).unwrap_or_else(
                |_| {
                    eprintln!("{}", &message);
                    process::exit(1);
                },
            ),
            FromStr::from_str(start_date.split('-').collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1]).unwrap_or_else(
                |_| {
                    eprintln!("{}", &message);
                    process::exit(1);
                },
            ),
            FromStr::from_str(start_date.split('-').collect::<Vec<&str>>()[2]).unwrap_or_else(
                |_| {
                    eprintln!("{}", &message);
                    process::exit(1);
                },
            ),
        )
        .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 1, 0)
        .timestamp_millis()
        .clamp(
            Utc.ymd(2016, 1, 1)
                .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0)
                .timestamp_millis(),
            Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        );
    let end_date_parsed: i64 = Utc
        .ymd(
            FromStr::from_str(end_date.split('-').collect::<Vec<&str>>()[0]).unwrap_or_else(|_| {
                eprintln!("{}", &message);
                process::exit(1);
            }),
            FromStr::from_str(end_date.split('-').collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1]).unwrap_or_else(|_| {
                eprintln!("{}", &message);
                process::exit(1);
            }),
            FromStr::from_str(end_date.split('-').collect::<Vec<&str>>()[2]).unwrap_or_else(|_| {
                eprintln!("{}", &message);
                process::exit(1);
            }),
        )
        .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 2, 0)
        .timestamp_millis()
        .clamp(
            Utc.ymd(2016, 1, 1)
                .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0)
                .timestamp_millis(),
            Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        );

    (start_date_parsed, end_date_parsed)
```

Mainly to remove the three arguments passed to `Utc.ymd` since they are doing the same, just using a different index, they are parsing dates such as "2021-01-01" and returning it in milliseconds and clamping it to a floor and ceiling.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com or https://users.rust-lang.org, if the code you've posted works but feels suboptimal.

Comment: Thank you for guidance, I will head over there. (And yes, the code works).

Comment: If anyone is interested in the answer (when it gets replied). https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rustacean-way-to-parse-a-date-rust/62669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with this refactoring

```rust
fn check_and_transform_dates(start_date: &str, end_date: &str) -> (i64, i64) {
    let message: String = format!(
        "Data could not be downloaded ❌, please make sure your dates
    are in the following format YYYY-MM-DD
    (ie. 2020-01-01), your dates are Start Date: {}, End Date: {}",
        &start_date, &end_date,
    );

    let earliest: NaiveDate = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2016, 1, 1);
    let today: NaiveDate = Utc::today().naive_utc();

    let parse_date = |date: &str| -> NaiveDate {
        let date: NaiveDate = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date, "%F").unwrap_or_else(|_| {
            eprintln!("{}", &message);
            process::exit(1);
        });
        if date < earliest {
            earliest
        } else if date > today {
            today
        } else {
            date
        }
    };

    (
        parse_date(start_date).and_hms(0, 0, 1).timestamp() * 1000,
        parse_date(end_date).and_hms(0, 0, 2).timestamp() * 1000,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can we call "Don't reinvent the wheel" a Rustacean way? Probably..

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a8e1efcb83402dc145c54e749a1a134)

You can use [`NaiveDate::parse_from_str`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.3.0/chrono/naive/date/struct.NaiveDate.html#method.parse_from_str), with a lot of formatting options.
You can then use `Utc::from_utc_date` or `Utc::from_local_date` to obtain the `Date` and process it later like you did

This reduces the code to:

```
use chrono::*;

fn check_and_transform_dates(start_date: &str, end_date: &str) -> (i64, i64) {
    let message: String = format!(
        "Data could not be downloaded ❌, please make sure your dates
    are in the following format YYYY-MM-DD
    (ie. 2020-01-01), your dates are Start Date: {}, End Date: {}",
        &start_date, &end_date,
    );
    let start_date = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        .expect(&message);
    let start_date_parsed: i64 = Utc.from_utc_date(&start_date)
        .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 1, 0)
        .timestamp_millis()
        .clamp(
            Utc.ymd(2016, 1, 1)
                .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0)
                .timestamp_millis(),
            Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        );
    let end_date = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        .expect(&message);
    let end_date_parsed: i64 = Utc.from_utc_date(&end_date)
        .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 2, 0)
        .timestamp_millis()
        .clamp(
            Utc.ymd(2016, 1, 1)
                .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0)
                .timestamp_millis(),
            Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        );

    (start_date_parsed, end_date_parsed)
}
```

That's where the question of code design comes, and it's opinion based. You see - you repeat the same code twice for processing start and end date - this code ideally should become a separate function.

```
use chrono::*;

fn parse_and_transform_date(date_str: &str) -> Result<i64, format::ParseError> {
    let date = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")?;
    let date_parsed: i64 = Utc.from_utc_date(&date)
        .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 1, 0)
        .timestamp_millis()
        .clamp(
            Utc.ymd(2016, 1, 1)
                .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0)
                .timestamp_millis(),
            Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        );
    Ok(date_parsed)
}
fn check_and_transform_dates(start_date: &str, end_date: &str) -> (i64, i64) {
    let start_date_result = parse_and_transform_date(start_date);
    let end_date_result = parse_and_transform_date(end_date);
    if let (Ok(start_date), Ok(end_date)) = (start_date_result, end_date_result) {
        return (start_date, end_date); // success
    }
    panic!(
        "Data could not be downloaded ❌, please make sure your dates
    are in the following format YYYY-MM-DD
    (ie. 2020-01-01), your dates are Start Date: {}, End Date: {}",
        &start_date, &end_date,
    );
}
```

Finally I would also let you consider a few problems:

1. It's not a good taste to abort your whole program with an error message like that, I would suggest `check_and_transform_dates` to instead return a `Result` and then considering this result, your calling code should handle the situation properly.
2. `check_and_transform_dates` should also probably do additional checks, e.g. check that `end_date` is not before `start_date`, etc

Example of fixing:

```
use chrono::*;

fn parse_and_transform_date(date_str: &str) -> Result<i64, format::ParseError> {
    let date = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")?;
    let date_parsed: i64 = Utc.from_utc_date(&date)
        .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 1, 0)
        .timestamp_millis()
        .clamp(
            Utc.ymd(2016, 1, 1)
                .and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0)
                .timestamp_millis(),
            Utc::now().timestamp_millis(),
        );
    Ok(date_parsed)
}

fn check_and_transform_dates(start_date: &str, end_date: &str) -> Option<(i64, i64)> {
    let start_date_result = parse_and_transform_date(start_date);
    let end_date_result = parse_and_transform_date(end_date);
    match (start_date_result, end_date_result) {
        (Ok(s), Ok(e)) if (s <= e) => Some((s, e)),
        _ => None
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", check_and_transform_dates("2020-01-02", "2020-01-03")
        .expect("Data could not be downloaded"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments, just learning common patterns, I posted the answer above

Answer (score 1):

*make a function for checking and clamping*
`fn check_and_clamp_date()` is needed for `start_date` and `end_date`

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::{Duration, NaiveDate, Utc};

static FMT: &str = "%Y-%m-%d";

fn check_and_clamp_date(date: &str, ceil_date: &str, floor_date: &str) -> Result<i64, String> {
    let ceil = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(ceil_date, FMT).expect("start corrupt");
    let floor = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(floor_date, FMT).expect("end corrupt");
    let r = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date, FMT);
    match r {
        Err(_) => Err("invalid date format".to_string()),
        Ok(d) => {
            let delta: Duration = d.clamp(ceil, floor).signed_duration_since(NaiveDate::from_ymd(1970, 1, 1));
            Ok(delta.num_nanoseconds().unwrap() / 1000000)
        },
    }
}

fn check_and_transform_dates(start_date: &str, end_date: &str) -> (i64, i64) {
    let message: String = format!(
        "Data could not be downloaded ❌, please make sure your dates
    are in the following format YYYY-MM-DD
    (ie. 2020-01-01), your dates are Start Date: {}, End Date: {}",
        &start_date, &end_date,
    );
    let now = Utc::now().format(FMT).to_string();
    let start = check_and_clamp_date(start_date, "2016-01-01", &now).expect(&message) + 1000;
    let end = check_and_clamp_date(end_date, "2016-01-01", &now).expect(&message) + 2000;
    (start, end)
}
```